# Android how to set color of specific item in GridView

Tags: android, arraylist, android-gridview

I have a `GridView` with an `Adapter` that creates a Calendar to show some events from my web server.

The data loads succesfully and when an item is clicked it shows the event. The thing is that i need to know which days have an event by setting up the background color of the item whithout the need of clicking them.

How can i achieve that?

This is the Adapter code:

```
public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    private java.util.Calendar month;
    public GregorianCalendar pmonth; // calendar instance for previous month
    /**
     * calendar instance for previous month for getting complete view
     */
    public GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
    private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
    int firstDay;
    int maxWeeknumber;
    int maxP;
    int calMaxP;
    int lastWeekDay;
    int leftDays;
    int mnthlength;
    String itemvalue, curentDateString;
    DateFormat df;

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    public static List<String> dayString;
    private View previousView;

    public CalendarAdapter(Context c, GregorianCalendar monthCalendar) {
        CalendarAdapter.dayString = new ArrayList<String>();
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        month = monthCalendar;
        selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) monthCalendar.clone();
        mContext = c;
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
        refreshDays();
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
        for (int i = 0; i != items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).length() == 1) {
                items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));
            }
        }
        this.items = items;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return dayString.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dayString.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        TextView dayView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
            // attributes
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);

        }
        dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        // separates daystring into parts.
        String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
        // taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02
        String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
        // checking whether the day is in current month or not.
        if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
            // setting offdays to white color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);
        } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            dayView.setClickable(false);
            dayView.setFocusable(false);
        } else {
            // setting curent month's days in blue color.
            dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        if (dayString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {
            setSelected(v);
            previousView = v;
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        dayView.setText(gridvalue);

        // create date string for comparison
        String date = dayString.get(position);

        if (date.length() == 1) {
            date = "0" + date;
        }
        String monthStr = "" + (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
        if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
            monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
        }

        // show icon if date is not empty and it exists in the items array
        ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
        if (date.length() > 0 && items != null && items.contains(date)) {
            iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            iw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        Log.e("color",""+CalendarView.color);
        if (CalendarView.color.equals("YELLOW")){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }else if (CalendarView.color.equals("RED")){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }

        return v;
    }

    public View setSelected(View view) {
        if (previousView != null) {
            previousView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }
        previousView = view;
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cel_selectl);
        return view;
    }

    public void refreshDays() {
        // clear items
        items.clear();
        dayString.clear();
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
        // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
        firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        // finding number of weeks in current month.
        maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
        mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
        maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
        calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...
        /**
         * Calendar instance for getting a complete gridview including the three
         * month's (previous,current,next) dates.
         */
        pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();
        /**
         * setting the start date as previous month's required date.
         */
        pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);

        /**
         * filling calendar gridview.
         */
        for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {

            itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
            pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
            dayString.add(itemvalue);

        }
    }

    private int getMaxP() {
        int maxP;
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                    month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }
        maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return maxP;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Calendar_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_cell"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#0000D7"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/date_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date"
        android:src="@drawable/dot"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `background color` for the required `Grid Item` depending on the item position

```
row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

But due to the `GridView` item view `recycle` , you will see the same background color set to some other items too.(since the view instance is same , only the data is different)

To fix this, you need to let `GridView` know that you have `two different type` of views ( one with color and other without color)

First `Override` `getViewTypeCount` and inform `GridView` that you have two view types

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Next, `Override` `getItemViewType` and let `GridView` know that which items position type is different. e.g., if the items `1 and 3` has events then `return 1`(some unique number) for those position and `return 0` for other positions

```
 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
    // return a unique number
    if(position == 1 || position == 3){
        return 1;
    }
   else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Finally, when `getView` is called. check for the position and set `background color` only for those specific items

```
 if(position == 1 || position == 3){
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
 }
```

This should work. perfectly. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i've tried your solution but is stil not working.

Comment: What was the issue now?

Comment: It's not changing the color of the grid item. =S

Comment: post your grid item layout `calendar_item`

Comment: Thanks, i've updated the OP with the calendar_item.xml layout

Answer (score 0):

get the id of your inflator parent layout and set like below:

```
LinearLayout f_l = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pr_bg);
        if (position % 3 == 0) {
            f_l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.campaignbase_black);
        } else if (position % 3 == 1) {
            f_l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.campaignbase_pink);
        } else if (position % 3 == 2) {
            f_l.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.campaignbase_brown);
        }
```